# How to remove question mark (character string) with PHP

Tags: php

I read unicode block string from the Wikipedia site 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)', but it had nothing to do with coding, and how to dont remove sometimes appears symbols like "�", Because this string doesn't know on the PHP language.

This is my Code (php):

```
<?php
$str1 = 'Apple iPhone X , 64GB , Space Gray';
$title1 = substr($str1, 0, 15) . '...'; 
echo str_replace('/[\s]+/','',$title1);
echo '<br>';
$str2 = 'ipod اجدد اصدار من ابل';
$title2 = substr($str2, 0, 15) . '...'; 
echo str_replace('/[\s]+/','',$title2);
?>
```

out :

```
Apple iPhone X ...
ipod اجدد �...
```

How to remove question mark '�'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is not php not understanding the char but the browser.

Simply change it to `&#xHEXCHAR;` but don't forget to replace `HEXCHAR` with the hexadecimal unicode representation of your character.

If you remove the `x`, you'll have to use the decimal representation of the char.

For example, the character `A` would be `&#65;` or `&#x41`

In your case, it would be:

```
'ipod &#x627 &#x62C; &#x62F; &#x62F; &#x20; &#x627; &#x635; &#x62F; &#x627; &#x631; &#x20; &#x645; &#x646; &#x20; &#x627; &#x628; &#x644;'
```

If you do this, don't forget to adjust the `substr` and `replace` method.

Escaping the chars could also be automated by getting the unicode representation of each char and replacing the char with `&#x`, the hexadecimal representation and `;`.

Comment: Not sure if this answers the question or was the only answer they could accept.  But the proper answer is in the duplicate.